# Should I call inverse_transform?

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I built a K-Nearest Neighbors Regressor GridSearchCV which calls a sklearn pipeline as the estimator.

Training appears to be working fine.  My confusion is after calling predict and checking the RMSE with the y_test.  Because I am using MinMaxScaler in the pipeline, I think I need to apply that tranformation to the y_test before calculating RMSE or inverse_tranform on the predicted X_test values.

Can anyone confirm this or direct me to the documentation that would clearly explain?  Full code below:

````
scalers = [('min_max', MinMaxScaler())]
estimators = [('knr', KNeighborsRegressor())]

knr_pipe = Pipeline(scalers + estimators)

# create KN-Regressor search space
knr_seach_space = {
    'knr__n_neighbors': [4,6,8,19,12],
    'knr__weights': ['uniform'],
    'knr__algorithm': ['auto', 'ball_tree', 'kd_tree', 'brute'],
    'knr__leaf_size': [10,20,30,40,50,60],
    'knr__p': [1,2]
}

knr_gs = GridSearchCV(estimator = knr_pipe,
                      param_grid = knr_search_space,
                      scoring = 'neg_root_mean_squared_error',
                      refit = 'neg_root_mean_squared_error',
                      cv = 5,
                      verbose = 4)

# train
knr_gs.fit(X_train, y_train)

# get predictions from best model
train_predictions = knr_gs.best_estimator_.predict(X_train)
test_predictions = knr_gs.best_estimator_.predict(X_test)

# get RMSE
# this is where I am confused... do I need to apply an inverse_transform on the X_test data before getting RMSE with y_test, OR should I transform the y_test data with the X_train/y_train fitted MinMaxScaler?

print(mean_squared_error(y_test, X_test, squared=False))

```
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not compare the X-Values with Y-Values, but the predicted Y-values with the real Y-Values. Hence, calling

```
print(mean_squared_error(y_test, test_predictions, squared=False))
```

should be what you are looking for.

Comment: Thats a typo on my part.  I'm actually comparing test_predictions (not X_test as I accidentally wrote above).

Comment: So, does predict apply an inverse transform to the X_test so they are back to the regular scale so that the RMSE is calculated correctly?

Answer (score 0):

After reading more documentation, I've come to understand that only the X values are scaled/transformed.  Thus, to Broele's point, the predictions are not scaled and no inverse_transform is needed to be called.